# Cassandra 3.3.0 - Triggers - data access from Partition

Tags: java, triggers, cassandra, cql, partition

I am using Cassandra 3.3.0 to store some data in a *ColumnFamily* created like that:

> CREATE COLUMNFAMILY inventory(objectid varint, timestamp varint,
>   numerator varint, data text, PRIMARY KEY ((objectid), timestamp,
>   numerator)) with clustering order by (timestamp desc, numerator asc);

After each new entry, I want to inform some third party application about new entries and its properties, but I am too stupid to access the changed data using the augment function.

```
public Collection<Mutation> augment(Partition update) {

    String key = null;
    String timestamp = null;
    String numerator = null;
    String data = null;

    try {
        UnfilteredRowIterator it = update.unfilteredIterator();
        CFMetaData cfMetaData = Schema.instance.getCFMetaData("keyspace", "inventory");

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Unfiltered un = it.next();
            Clustering clt = (Clustering) un.clustering();  
            Iterator<Cell> cls = update.getRow(clt).cells().iterator();

            while(cls.hasNext()){
                Cell cell = cls.next();
                data = new String(cell.value().array());
            }
            un.toString(cfMetaData); //RETURNS timestamp, numerator and data as one string.... 
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

*update.toString()* returns all information in a String, including the ones I want, but I actually do not want to parse it through. Does anybody know how to access the values of "objectid", "timestamp" and "numerator" directly?